# How to convert the object of Uint8Array to string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432239/how-to-convert-the-object-of-uint8array-to-string-and-convert-back-string-to-sam). I see the answer but I couldn't understand how I can do it. Is there any other suggestions?

My code is:

```
var eccrypto = require("eccrypto");
var w,actual;
var publicKey = Buffer.from([4, 86, 82, 58, 244, 11, 140, 41, 132, 245, 184, 162, 163, 98, 49, 119, 168, 235, 252, 50, 6, 91, 147, 191, 190, 61, 65, 63, 101, 164, 132, 213, 188, 106, 26, 203, 171, 215, 240, 151, 7, 193, 10, 151, 103, 107, 1, 135, 117, 225, 5, 41, 55, 57, 18, 205, 98, 178, 82, 135, 170, 111, 188, 98, 57],'hex');

var privateKey= Buffer.from([238, 239, 199, 101, 188, 134, 13, 13, 195, 172, 125, 168, 225, 189, 72, 148, 225, 200, 127, 218, 204, 11, 150, 146, 180, 243, 195, 109, 200, 119, 50, 20],'hex');

eccrypto.encrypt(publicKey, Buffer.from("message")).then(function(encrypted) {
    console.log(encrypted)

    let encoded =JSON.stringify(encrypted)
    w=encoded;
    console.log(encoded)

    actual = JSON.parse((encoded))
    console.log(actual)
});

eccrypto.decrypt(privateKey,actual).then(function(plaintext) {
    console.log("Message to part B:", plaintext.toString()); 
});
```

When I use `actual` variable I have this error:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Bad public key
> ```

this the output of encrypted :

[image]

this the output of encoded :

[image]

and this the output of actual "there is some things changes i think, is not it ?":
[image]
thank you advance.

Comment: decrypt is expecting a Buffer where it is being given a JSON. Maybe that is why promise is failing. Try sending encrypted eccrypto.decrypt(privateKey, encrypted)

Comment: After fixing the error from `encrypt`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572) for the next problem

Comment: @alchemist95 actually this is work but i need to save encrypted at this format : `let encoded =JSON.stringify(encrypted)` to use it somewhere then i want to convert it again to the original format using `var actual = JSON.parse((encoded))`
Is my way wrong ?

Comment: @Bergi thank you very much, but i use async and await to handle this problem i think it works.

Comment: @norah Cool, it should work when you switched from `.then()` to `await`, but the code you posted in the question didn't use `async`/`await`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah because it a long code and i am just show the related code of my question, thanks a lot, i appreciate your help.

Comment: adding an image in answer. See if that helps @norah

Comment: @alchemist95 i update the question, Can you have a look ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While parsing, you need to send a reviver function, which conditionally parses the object. If you see how encoded looks, you will understand why the reviver function needs to be written this way.

[image]

Comment: it does not work, actual variable it is an object,  have a look to the question to understand what i mean, i updated it. thank you

Comment: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify)) is modifying the Buffer type which is why decrypt will keep failing. In order for decrypt() to work, you need to send a Buffer type object, not a regular JSON object.

Comment: you mean in my case i have to make it like this: `JSON.parse(encrypted)` ? if it yes, it give me this error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 .. if not, can you explain it to me further. thanks a lot.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to convert encrypted into a string. Correct? Secondly, you want to be able to retrieve the encypted buffer from that string. Right?

Comment: JSON.parse expects a string, that's why it is failing. Ideally, `encoded = encrypted.toString('hex'); const actual = Buffer.from(encoded) ;` should solve your problem

Comment: yeah, at the end i want: actual = encrypted, when i do what you suggest and try `console.log(encoded)` the result is : [object Object] 
it does not give me a real string!

Comment: Please check answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the "hex" encoding parameter from your `Buffer.from`.